# Config server's networking over ssh

Tags: networking, configuration, ssh, admin

I had a few dedicated servers. Their location is unknown to me (maybe at North Pole). Obviously, I use SSH to access them and do configuration.

Now I need to config their networking (i.e NIC, IP, bridge, routing etc). Each of them has only one NIC. As the result, everytime I enter 'service networking restart', the ssh connection is broken. Even worse if there is something wrong with the configuration, I completely lose connection with the servers.

I wonder how administrators can config networking without staying in datacenters.

Sorry for such a dummy question, but I wonder is there any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Shell scripts and screen/tmux.

Put together all of the networking commands you want to accomplish in a bash script (or perl or whatever suits you) and run it in screen or tmux to maintain your session (you'll still have to reconnect of course but at least you'll start where you left off)

Comment: I'm trying to put everything in bash scripts now. But what if there is a mistake in script, or the config is just wrong, how can we ensure we'll start where we left off (the connectivity is lost). I wonder if there is any virtual tool in Linux to help.

Comment: You'll still start where you left off but if you make a mistake or a config is wrong you may not be able to reconnect (a ticket to the DC is never fun). I usually test my scripts on a local VM before sending them out for use on remote machines I would suggest the same for you.

Comment: Thank you JasonSec. So only choice is to be more careful from now on.
Indeed, it's quite annoying to send ticket to DC and wait for them.